# Stop moving ball on Button click

Tags: android

I have a ball that keeps moving from start. I want to stop ball on button click. When I clicked on button it show the Toast, but the ball keep on moving. It doesn't stop.

Please guide me how to stop ball on button click. My code for Activity is there.

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class BounceActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int GAME_START = 500;
    private static final int GAME_STOP = 600;

    Thread myRefreshThread = null;
    BounceView myBounceView = null;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    Handler myGUIUpdateHandler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case BounceActivity.GAME_START:
                myBounceView.invalidate();
                break;
            case BounceActivity.GAME_STOP:
                Log.d("BounceView", "Game state: " + BounceView.game_state);
                Toast.makeText(BounceActivity.this, "Game stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myRefreshThread = null;
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        this.myBounceView = new BounceView(this, dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
        this.setContentView(myBounceView);
        myRefreshThread = new Thread(new RefreshRunner());
        myRefreshThread.start();
    }

    class RefreshRunner implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (myRefreshThread != null) {
                if(BounceView.game_state == 0) {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    msg.what = BounceActivity.GAME_START;
                    myGUIUpdateHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                } else if (BounceView.game_state == 1) {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    msg.what = BounceActivity.GAME_STOP;
                    myGUIUpdateHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing and setting myRefreshThread on different threads, which can be problematic.

Instead of checking if myRefreshThread is null in your while loop, you can add a "running" flag to RefreshRunner, and a stop method that sets it to false.
Than check that flag in the while loop.

Hold a reference to your RefreshRunner (the one you pass to myRefreshThread), and call stop() when you want the animation to stop.

```
class RefreshRunner implements Runnable {

    private void mRunning = true;

    public void stop () {
          mRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRunning) {
            if(BounceView.game_state == 0) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = BounceActivity.GAME_START;
                myGUIUpdateHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            } else if (BounceView.game_state == 1) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = BounceActivity.GAME_STOP;
                myGUIUpdateHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

}}
```